# Email not sending on new order in magento

Tags: php, email, magento, ssl, cron

I am using `magento 1.8.1 version`. After place a successful order email not sending to customer. Even contact form also not working. In-short magento can't sending any email. Already follow many questions here but not helping me.

Currently I used Gmail services for email with SMTP Pro Email Extension.

Here is I've already tried :

**In magento - SMTP Pro's > General settings** :

Email Connection - Custom SMTP
Username - info@website.in
Password - •••••••••••••••
Host - smtp.gmail.com
Port - 587
SSL Security - SSL TLS

Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/8upq6c

---

**In magento - System > Mail Sending Settings** :

Disable Email Communications - No
Host - localhost
Port - 25
Set Return Path - No

---

**Cron Job Set up with cPanel :**

```
*/5**** php /home/username/public_html/eshop/cron.php
```

Cron.php/Cron.sh files are already added.

Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/8upqca

---

General things might be you need from me :

1. Email service working in cPanel. No issue from hosting.
2. Sales Emails - All the emails are Enabled

This is what i have done. 
If you have any idea please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Is you your magento root is public_html/eshop or public_html

Comment: Thank you for your replay.. It's `public_html/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After, a long research i found just simple solution :

I just input these wrong fields in SMTP Pro's > General settings :

```
Username - info@website.in
Password - •••••••••••••••
```

Simply changed it with my cPanel username / password and now it's working fine.

Thank you!